# libnode-dev installation within docker container

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, docker-compose, raspbian, debian-buster

I'm trying to run a node.js application.

I **can** run it without problems directly on my raspbian buster.

Within a docker container running on the same raspberry pi, I have no such luck.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM balenalib/raspberry-pi2-debian-node:10-stretch-run

RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get -y install g++ python make git

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package.json

RUN JOBS=MAX npm install --production
COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

But when I run the same node.js code within a docker container, I'm getting a libnode.so.64 error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/rpi-lora-sensorified/data $ docker logs rpi-lora-sensorified_data_1

> resin-websocket@1.0.1 start /usr/src/app
> node index.js

/usr/src/app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:121
        throw e;
        ^

Error: libnode.so.64: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried installing libnode-dev (which I've concluded provides this library) within the container, but I'm getting a

```
E: Unable to locate package libnode-dev
```

And yes, I've rebuilt the container without cache but still cannot locate that package.

Any (like really even some pointers would help) idea where do I continue to look further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution that I can't explain at all is:
I was trying to run the code on debian stretch, while testing if it works on debian buster.. When updating the docker image to buster, everthing works as expected.